# How to invert a list of percentages (list of shares) with respect to their underlying ratio

Tags: inverse, transformation, percentages

Best, how do you invert a list shares with respect to their underlying ratio.

E.g. If i've 2 persons A and B with their respectfully values 3 - 1
then I want to know their *inverse shares*

```
A = 3 --> 75%    what I want -->  25%  <-- result
B = 1 --> 25%                -->  75%  <-- result
```

The above example is +/- easy  **(1-percentage)** 
But now I want to know *(the formula | methode)* 
for when I've multiple users :

```
person  share  perc.
A       1      0,083333333
B       2      0,166666667
C       3      0,25
D       6      0,5
```

Then i just can't use the same logic anymore
also, not (1-perc.)/(N-1)

```
per s   percentage  1-percentag dev_by_3
A   1   0,083333333 0,916666667 0,305555556
B   2   0,166666667 0,833333333 0,277777778
C   3   0,25        0,75        0,25
D   6   0,5         0,5         0,166666667

  sum_s sum_percent sum_1-per   sum_dev_by_3
    12  1           3           1
```

But what you'll see is. In the beginning, there was a **x6** ratio between A and D but after this, the ratio is **< 2**. Which isn't correct I think (for my purpose)

What I would like to see is, a transformation of 1 2 3 6 into percentages whereby the highest values get the lowest value. but with respect to the initial ratio.
A should be 6 times smaller then D, B should be 3 times smaller then D,  C should be 2 times smaller then D

(note, it should be programmable in python without to much of complexity) (if possible | a formula would be nice))

kind regards

Dieter

Comment: So we're talking about a parametrization of the values here, and you want a small input value to result in a large output value. You could very well define a parameter
$$
f(s,\text{total}) = \frac{\text{total}}{s}
$$
where $\text{total}$ is the total number of shares. Surely, $f\geq1$ always but is there a reason why it shouldn't be? By the way, what is the reason you even want to do this transformation?

Comment: Matti - At the moment i'm working on a scoring system ( you can compare it with the ELO-rating system). But this scoring is only calculated on a group level. But as soon as the team loses a game they will receive  a negative reating,  e.g. -100 points   -- these points will be distributed based on the performance of each player. This means - if a player performed well,  you want to give that player less negative points    in comparison with a player who performed very pore (and might be the reason why they lost.)   --   if they won,  then we will just use the  percentage | shares

Comment: @MattiP. - It worked :) Didn't expect it would be that easy XD  feel i bit stupid now :p

Comment: I'm glad to hear :)